# How do I store an image source inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on the image, another image will show up on the same page but as of right now when I click the image it only gives me the picture link instead of giving me the picture.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>

<p>JavaScript array elements are accessed using numeric indexes (starting from 0).</p>

<p id="output"></p>
   
<img id="ima1" src="https://i.imgur.com/pe18NpF.jpg" style="width:150px">
<div id="image1"></div>
<script>
var images = [
    'https://i.imgur.com/xwZRPaT.jpg'
];

document.getElementById("ima1").addEventListener("click", showPic4);
function showPic4() {
document.getElementById("image1").innerHTML = images[0];
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first issue with your JavaScript is in this line here:

```js
document.getElementById("image1").innerHTML = images[0];
```

What you're doing here is that you are getting the HTML Element with the id "image1" and then setting its inner HTML to the value in images[0].

The reason you're getting the picture's link instead of the image is because the value inside images[0] is a string, not an image.

There are many ways to achieve your original goal. One way, keeping consistency with your current code is to target an img tag's src attribute. Consider the code block below:

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://large-type.com/twitter-card.png?v2" style='width:150px'>
<img id="img2" style='width:150px'></img>
<script>
    var images = [
        'https://images.megapixl.com/5692/56920966.jpg'
    ];

    document.getElementById("img1").addEventListener("click", showPic);
    
    function showPic() {
        document.getElementById("img2").setAttribute('src', images[0]);
    }
</script>
```

The difference here is that the HTML element the showPic function is targetting is an img element instead of a div. Now we can just add an img src like you did for the first image using the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Image source (link) must be associated to its img tag to work with `innerHTML`
Here `srcdata` holds img element:

```
document.getElementById("ima1").addEventListener("click", showPic4);
function showPic4() {
   var srcdata="<img id='ima1'  src="+images[0]+"  style='width:150px'>";
   document.getElementById("image1").innerHTML = srcdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, You've only got a string of text. You need to either target an existing `<img>` and modify the `src` attribute or create a new `<img>`. I've done the second option.

There are a lot of ways to do this, and a lot of dispute on which ways are the best.

```js
var images = [
  'https://i.imgur.com/xwZRPaT.jpg'

];

document.getElementById("ima1").addEventListener("click", showPic4);

function showPic4() {
  document.getElementById("image1").innerHTML = "<img src=" + images[0] + ">";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>

  <p>JavaScript array elements are accessed using numeric indexes (starting from 0).</p>

  <p id="output"></p>

  <img id="ima1" src="https://i.imgur.com/pe18NpF.jpg" style="width:150px">
  <div id="image1"></div>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, it was a simple and quick fix @John is there any way to attach some css style to the end of the "<img src=" + images[0] + ">"; part, I want to add a border/outline to the picture.